# How to add values to url on python request

Tags: python, url, request

I wanna get data from an api and I use this: requests.get("https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/woeid/2013/4/i/"). I want woeid to be a variable and i be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) syntax to substitute variable names for values in a string.

```
woeid = "2487956"
i = 12
url = f"https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/{woeid}/2013/4/{i}/"
print(url)
response = requests.get(url)
```

The url becomes:
`https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/2013/4/12/`

Answer (score 1):

The longer and more time consuming version of CodeMonkey's answer would be

```
woeid = "2487956"
i = 12
url = "https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/" + woeid + "/2013/4" + i "/"
print(url)
response = requests.get(url)
```

Reason why I added this is because, string interpolation isnt supported by all languages.